# Proxy server with squid and multiple 4G routers

Tags: router, iptables, raspberry-pi, squid

A particular Raspberry Pi 4 is connected to `wlan0` (`192.168.10.174`) on a 4G router (`192.168.10.1`) and has a 4G mobile connection.

Already on interface `eth0` (`192.168.1.41`), is my local network router (`192.168.1.254`) with internet ISP.

Knowing this information, how do I create a local proxy server (Using Squid?) so that I can connect via another network device (example `192.168.1.42`) and use the internet from the 4G router from the `wlan0` interface of the Raspberry Pi?

I used the following settings in Squid, but apparently it didn't work:

```
http_port 3128
cache_peer wlan0 parent 8080 0 no-query default
never_direct allow all
```

If I just use `http_port 3128` it will work, but it will use the system default gateway which is set to eth0.
However, I need this gateway to be defined in squid, because in the future I will have 10 routers to create different ports in squid, one being used for each public ip of the router.

Also, I believe you need iptables entries.

How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

run multiple Squid's , each in separate Cgroup's created with this script

https://gist.github.com/akruis/da385170f33799112df713ec7c3e9305

or

https://gist.github.com/level323/54a921216f0baaa163127d960bfebbf0